# kotlin.NoWhenBranchMatchedException under unit testing a tailrec function with arrow-kt in the mix

Tags: kotlin, mockito, arrow-kt

I'm testing a function with an external dependency inside of a `tailrec` function. The function returns an `Either`.
When mocking this dependency, I'm providing a single mock invocation. I get the following exception:
`kotlin.NoWhenBranchMatchedException`

Why is the exception occurring and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The exception occurs because I'm only providing one invocation of the mock to Mockito. For the invocation of this `tailrec` function, the function is executing twice, hence first going to the right case, then to the left, and causing the exception to be thrown since I'm not providing a left case mock.

To fix the issue provide another invocation of the mock (another right case), causing the `tailrec` to return up the call stack.